# ShieldUI Wicket Editable Grid

Tags: hibernate, wicket, shieldui

Hi I currently have a project which has been completed but based on new requirements some changes need to be made. My project currently uses Wicket and also Hibernate and displays data in a table format. What is now required is to make the data table editable and once changed by the user, needs to be saved to a database.

I have investigated for weeks for a proper solution on how to do so and came across ShieldUI's editable grid. I would like to know how easily it will be to use ShieldUI and Wicket and if any concrete documentation exists.

If any other editable grid frameworks are advised I'll take them into consideration as well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with the ShieldUI integration but you can check https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/editable-grid-parent and https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/inmethod-grid-parent. Both of them support inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

The Wicket ShieldUI library is a set of wrappers around the ShieldUI's JavaScript&HTML suite, and the settings, events and functionality in the Wicket code mirror the JavaScript ones.

There are very comprehensive [documentation](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/java.apache.wicket/getting.started) and [demos](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage) for all ShieldUI widgets, including the Grid.

There is also the [wicket-shieldui-examples](https://github.com/shieldui/wicket-shieldui/tree/master/wicket-shieldui-examples) project on GitHub, that can be used for referencing specific Apache Wicket examples.

Last, if you become an owner of a commercial license, you will be able to get dedicated support, which might help you with any development issues you might experience.